# Proper conjugation when using "trio"

Tags: word-usage, collective-nouns, conjugation

I have a question regarding word usage when using "trio" in a sentence.

Here's an example sentence:

> The trio tries to find the way but appear to be lost.

Should "tries" be in the third person, or should it remain "try"? The example will apply to other cases in which another word instead of "try" was used, but an answer to this will help clarify this for me in the future.

Comment: Collective nouns are singular, generally. Some collective nouns in some cases are treated as plural in modern British English, but American English does not do this, and British English does not do this in all circumstances.